# Getting a list of private properties of Java class / object

Tags: java, reflection

How can I get a list of all the private properties of Java object used in getters and setters. I tried `PropertyUtils` and `MethodUtils` but no luck. Now I am trying to use `getDeclaredFields()` of the Class object which returns me a list of Field objects and then check if that is a private property is that a way to go? Or are there any better solutions to this.

Answer (score 3):

This is quite old question post but i'll provide an answer here for the sake of new searches.

Using the approach provided by @highlycaffeinated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6796254/776860

You can easily come up with a desired solution with a couple of changes.

#### Retrieving a list of private field names only

```
public List<String> getMap(Object o) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
    Field[] declaredFields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        if(!field.isAccessible()) {
            result.add(field.getName());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

#### Retrieving a Map of all field names and their values

```
public Map<String, Object> getMap(Object o) throws IllegalArgumentException, IllegalAccessException {
    Map<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    Field[] declaredFields = o.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
    for (Field field : declaredFields) {
        field.setAccessible(true);
        result.put(field.getName(), field.get(o));
        } 
    }
    return result;
}
```

Exactly like @highlycaffeinated provided just with the additional line `field.setAccessible(true);` which enables you to introspect `private` fields too.

Answer (score 1):

What you said, or maybe `yourBean.getClass().getMethods()` 
and then `method.getName().startsWith("get")` on each method returned.

May I ask why you need to do this for?

Comment: I have a few custom properties for a Java class coming in from the request which needs to get into a hashmap (it's one of the property). And this object is a type parameter so I am using reflection to create and populate this object.

Answer (score 1):

You could look for all the getters and setters and look to see if there is a matching field.  However fields can start with `_fieldName` or `m_fieldName`  You can only infer the getters/setters has something to do with the field.

Answer (score 0):

I am doing this:

```
private Set<String> getModelProperties(Class<T> cls) {
    Set<String> properties = new HashSet<String>();
    for (Method method : cls.getDeclaredMethods()) {
        String methodName = method.getName();
        if (methodName.startsWith("set")) {
            properties.add(Character.toLowerCase(
              methodName.charAt(0)) + methodName.substring(3));
        }
    }

    return properties;
}
```