# Serialize POJO to application/x-www-form-urlencoded representation of the object

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am using Spring/SpringMVC and I want to serialize a POJO to application/x-www-form-urlencoded representation - the very same representation that a Spring @Controller would be able to bind to a POJO if submitted via a POST request for example.

Anyone has an idea in which Spring Components should I be looking?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [this](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.6.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/converter/FormHttpMessageConverter.html) HTTP message converter implementation. Register that in Spring MVC configuration on the server-side or a `RestTemplate` on the client side.

Comment: I don't want to create the MultiValueMap, but Spring to do it for me. :) I have complex POJO with multiple properties - each few layers deep.

Comment: My guess there is nothing out of the box to do the object => map conversion for you. Have a look at this thread for ideas: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796187/java-introspection-object-to-map