# Java: Most efficient way to map properties of one list of objects to another

Tags: java, list, loops, design-patterns, mapping

I'm looking for an efficient design pattern to map one list of objects to another list of objects with zero-or-one-to-one relationships between them. I realize this sort of thing is typically done in a relational database, but in this particular case it really needs to be done in the Java application...

Let's say the first list contains `Foo` objects (i.e. `List<Foo>`):

```
public class Foo {
    public Integer id;
    public String barName;
}
```

And the second list contains `Bar` objects (i.e. `List<Bar>`):

```
public class Bar {
    public Integer fooId;
    public String name;
}
```

How can I most efficiently map all `name` properties from `Bar` to the `Foo` object where `Bar.fooId` equals `Foo.id`?

The best I can think of is this:

```
void mapFooBar(List<Foo> fooList, List<Bar> barList) {
    for (Bar bar : barList) {
        for (Foo foo : fooList) {
            if (bar.fooId.equals(foo.id)) foo.barName = bar.name;
        }
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** Based on several answers, I have improved my code as follows:

```
void mapFooBar(List<Foo> fooList, List<Bar> barList) {
    Map<Integer, String> barMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();
    for (Bar bar : barList)
        barMap.put(bar.fooId, bar.name);

    for (Foo foo : fooList)
        if (barMap.containsKey(foo.id)) foo.barName = barMap.get(foo.id);
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you familiar with [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) interface?

Comment: Better use solutions from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6796187/java-introspection-object-to-map.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is something like Apache [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) or [Springs](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.0.M1/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanUtils.html) implementation. Just make sure the properties are named the same between the 2 objects you want to copy the data between. So taking your code:

```
void mapFooBar(List<Foo> fooList, List<Bar> barList) {
  for (Bar bar : barList) {
    for (Foo foo : fooList) {
        if (bar.fooId.equals(foo.id)) {
            BeanUtils.copyProperties(foo, bar);
        }
    }
  }
}
```

Now that the copy is done lets look at your loop.  Your best bet would be to keep the Objects in Maps using fooId as the key (assuming no objects duplicated).

```
void mapFooBar(Map<Integer, Foo> fooMap, Map<Integer, Bar> barMap) {
  for (Integer key : fooMap.keySet()) {
    if (barMap.containsKey(key) {
      Bar bar = barMap.get(key);
      Foo foo = fooMap.get(key);
      BeanUtils.copyProperties(foo, bar);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response! I agree with your suggestion for improving the loop using a map, as others have suggested, but I don't see the benefit of using `BeanUtils.copyProperties(foo, bar)` since I only need to map a single property.

Comment: Gotcha, I thought you only put in a single property as an example.  Leave out the BeanProperties then.

Answer (score 1):

This has complexity of `N * M` that means if you have 5 foo and 8 bar it would have to execute loop for 40 times

```
class Container{

  List<Foo> foos;
  List<Bar> bars;

}
```

if you use `Map<Integer, Container>` it would be `N + M`  (5 + 8 = 13 times)

iterate through both list once and map it with `id`

---

**Also See**

- [java 8 parallel stream, filter](http://download.java.net/jdk8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html)

Comment: Thank you for your response. I don't quite follow...could you illustrate how this would be used to map values from `bars` to `foos`?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. Assuming the "primary keys" were unique I might convert the list of Bar to a map with fooId as the key and either whole object or the name as the value.  Then I would iterate through the list of Foo and see whether the id property existed in the map.  If it did I would map the bar.name to foo.barName;

Comment: Thanks for the response! Based on your answer and @Jigar's answer, I see that looping through List<Bar> once to create a map, then looping through List<Foo> once to check against the map keys, is more efficient than doing the nested loop. And yes, my ids are unique.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Orika, an efficient Java Object to Object Mapping

https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika

Answer (score 1):

In Java 1.8 you can write it like this:

```
void mapFooBar(List<Foo> fooList, List<Bar> barList) {

    Map<Integer, String> barMap = new HashMap<Integer, String>();

    barList.stream()
        .forEach(bar -> barMap.put(bar.fooId, bar.name));

    fooList.stream()

        // replaces if statement
        .filter(foo -> barMap.containsKey(foo.id))

        // update the bar name
        .forEach(foo -> {
            foo.barName = barMap.get(foo.id);
        });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HashMap to store all Foo objects, with their id as key.

Then loop through Bar list and access directly HashMap position you want

Comment: What type of HashMap because I have attributes of type String, Integer and sql.Date